# GridView not displaying data inside a panel

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I'm working on a system which searches for people then displays all who fit the relevant search criteria underneath in a GridView but no data is being displayed and its really frustrating me. 
This is the panel/gridview from PatientSearch.aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlUpdate" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlResults" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" >
                <asp:GridView ID="gvSearch" runat="server" Font-Names = "Arial" Font-Size = "11pt" ForeColor = "#000000"
                    onselectedindexchanged="gvSearch_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" DataKeyNames="patientid" AllowPaging = "true"
                    OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" PageSize = "10" Width = "100%" HeaderStyle-BackColor = "#465c71" HeaderStyle-ForeColor = "#ffffff"> 

                    <Columns>
                        <%--Creates a select button that appear at the start of the grid view--%>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton Text="Select" ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HC Number" ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%--This will be the first field to appear beside the select button--%>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblHCNum" Text='<%# Eval("HC_Number") %>' runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                            <%--Bound fields will place them in a specific order--%>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "PatientNumber" HeaderText="Patient Number"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "Surname" HeaderText="Surname"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "Forename" HeaderText="Forename"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "ReferredBy" HeaderText="Consultant" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "Sex" HeaderText="Sex"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "DateOfBirth" HeaderText = "Date Of Birth" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "AppointmentDate" HeaderText = "Appointment Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />

                    </Columns> 
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvSearch" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This code is from the PatientSearch.aspx.cs for the GridView etc

```
 public partial class PatientSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //As this is the first page the user will have contact with when logged in this is where the limits of what they can and cannot do 
        //Are created to be used on all pages

        //Open connection to database
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OepdSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))

        {
            //Select columns required 
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [RoleName], [AddPermission], [EditPermission], [DeletePermission] FROM aspnet_Roles"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        //Fill required columns into datatable
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                        //Create stringbuilder to store RoleNames
                        StringBuilder addPermission = new StringBuilder();
                        StringBuilder editPermission = new StringBuilder();
                        StringBuilder deletePermission = new StringBuilder();

                        //Iterate through the datatable and add each correct row to the stringbuilder
                        for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

                            //only add the necessary rows to the string builder
                            if (dr["AddPermission"].ToString() == "True")
                                addPermission.AppendLine(string.Join(",", dr.ItemArray));

                            if (dr["EditPermission"].ToString() == "True")
                                editPermission.AppendLine(string.Join(",", dr.ItemArray));

                            if (dr["DeletePermission"].ToString() == "True")
                                deletePermission.AppendLine(string.Join(",", dr.ItemArray));
                        }

                        //Remove the unnecessary data from the string
                        addPermission.Replace(",True", ""); addPermission.Replace(",False", "");
                        editPermission.Replace(",True", ""); editPermission.Replace(",False", "");
                        deletePermission.Replace(",True", ""); deletePermission.Replace(",False", "");

                        //Convert stringbuilder to string to allow it to be compared
                        var add = addPermission.ToString();
                        var edit = editPermission.ToString();
                        var delete = deletePermission.ToString();

                        //Retrieve all roles the current user has access to
                        var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);

                        if (!userRoles.Any(u => add.Contains(u)))
                        {
                            btnNewRecord.Enabled = false;
                        }

                        //Store what permissions are granted to which roles
                        Session["AddPermission"] = add;
                        Session["EditPermission"] = edit;
                        Session["DeletePermission"] = delete;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["DS"];

       // if (ds == null)
        //{
            //Make the menu inaccessable if no record has been selected, Due to menu being ambiguous System.Web.UI.WebControls is required
            //System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu MyMasterMenu = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu)Master.FindControl("NavigationMenu");
            //MyMasterMenu.Visible = false;
        //}

        //Hide the export buttons if the gridview is empty
        if (gvSearch.DataSource == null)
        {
            //imgWord.Visible = false; 
            imgExcel.Visible = false;
            lblExport.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //imgWord.Visible = true; 
            imgExcel.Visible = true;
            lblExport.Visible = true;
        }

        //Hide label that catches any errors from user
        lblErrors.Visible = false;

        if (Session["RecordSuccessfullyDeleted"] != null)
        {
            //Message that has been passed from another page, informs the user that the record has ben successfully deleted
            string deletedID = Session["RecordSuccessfullyDeleted"].ToString();
            lblErrors.Text = deletedID + " Succesfully Deleted!";

            //calls the popup to display a notification
            dvMsg.Visible = true;
            lblMsg.Text = "" + lblErrors.Text;

            //To prevent message appearing multiple times
            Session["RecordSuccessfullyDeleted"] = null;
        }
        else
        {
            dvMsg.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    //Tells the page what to do once the user has selected a patient
    protected void gvSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int index = gvSearch.SelectedIndex;

        string strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OepdSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConString);
        myConnect.ConnectionString = strConString;

        string strCommandText = "prcPersonalSelectedByPatientIdRetrieve";

        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PatientNumber", gvSearch.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString()));

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
            da.Fill(ds, "personal");

            //Needed to reset the clinical eval page for newly selected patient
            Session["NDS"] = null;
        }

        catch (Exception fe)
        {
            lblMoreErrors.Text = "Error: " + fe.Message;
        }

        try
        {
            //Assigns the selected patients details to the dataset and redirects the user to the personal page
            Session["DS"] = ds;
            Response.Redirect("~/UserPages/PatientDetails.aspx");
        }

        catch (Exception er)
        {
            lblErrors.Text = "Error: " + er.Message;
        }
    }

    //Tells the gridview what to do when the page change is selected
    protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataBindSearch();
        gvSearch.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gvSearch.DataBind();
    }

    protected void BtnResetSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Deletes all current criteria enetered and refreshes the page
        Session["ViewState"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("~/UserPages/PatientSearch.aspx");
    }

    protected void BtnSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Sets the panel properties after the button is clicked, this helps avoid the empty white 
        //space at the bottom if the property is assigned when nothing is there
        pnlResults.Style.Add("height", "500px");
        this.DataBindSearch();
    }
    protected void BtnAddPatient(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Remove("DS");
        Response.Redirect("~/UserPages/AddPatient.aspx", false);
    }
    protected void DataBindSearch()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OepdSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConString);
        myConnect.ConnectionString = strConString;

        string strCommandText = "prcPersonalByPatientIdSelect";

        //Now allows partial searches eg. Surname: M will return all surnames with M in it
        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (txtPatientNumber.Text != "")
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PatientNumber", txtPatientNumber.Text));
            }

            if (txtHCNumber.Text != "___-___-____")
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HC_Number", txtHCNumber.Text));
            }

            if (txtPatientSurname.Text != "")
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Surname", txtPatientSurname.Text));
            }

            if (txtPatientFirstName.Text != "")
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Forename", txtPatientFirstName.Text));
            }

            if (dpdConsultant.Text != "")
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Consultant", dpdConsultant.Text));
            }

            if (dpdSex.Text != "")
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sex", dpdSex.Text));
            }


            //Date of Birth Search
            if (txtDateOfBirth.Text != "")
            {
                //Required for use of between dates
                string dateDoB = txtDateOfBirth.Text;
                DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateDoB);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirth", date));
            }
            if (txtDateOfBirthTo.Text != "")
            {
                if (txtDateOfBirthTo.Text == "*")
                {
                    //Carries out the funtion of the wildcard
                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirthEnd", now));
                }
                else
                {
                    //Required for use of between dates
                    string dateDoB = txtDateOfBirthTo.Text;
                    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateDoB);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirthEnd", date));
                }
            }

            //Diagnosis Date Search
            if (txtDiagnosisDate.Text != "")
            {
                //Required for use of between dates
                string dateDD = txtDiagnosisDate.Text;
                DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateDD);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DiagnosisDate", date));
            }
            if (txtDiagnosisDateTo.Text != "")
            {
                if (txtDiagnosisDateTo.Text == "*")
                {
                    //Carries out the funtion of the wildcard
                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DiagnosisDateEnd", now));
                }
                else
                {
                    //Required for use of between dates
                    string dateDD = txtDiagnosisDateTo.Text;
                    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateDD);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DiagnosisDateEnd", date));
                }
            }

            //Examination Date Search
            if (txtAppointmentDate.Text != "")
            {
                //Required for use of between dates
                string dateED = txtAppointmentDate.Text;
                DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateED);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AppointmentDate", date));
            }

            if (txtAppointmentDateEnd.Text != "")
            {
                if (txtAppointmentDateEnd.Text == "*")
                {
                    //Carries out the funtion of the wildcard
                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AppointmentDateEnd", now));
                }
                else
                {
                    //Required for use of between dates
                    string dateAD = txtAppointmentDateEnd.Text;
                    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateAD);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AppointmentDateEnd", date));
                }
            }


            //Age at Examination Search
            if (txtAgeAtExamination.Text != "")
            {
                //Required for use of between dates
                string Age = txtAgeAtExamination.Text;
                DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(Age);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Age", date));
            }

            if (txtAgeAtExaminationTo.Text != "")
            {
                if (txtAgeAtExamination.Text == "*")
                {
                    //Carries out the funtion of the wildcard
                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AgeEnd", now));
                }
                else
                {
                    //Required for use of between dates
                    string Age = txtAgeAtExamination.Text;
                    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(Age);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AgeEnd", date));
                }
            }

            //EXAMINATION CHECKBOXES
            //Full-field ERG Checkbox
            if (chkERG.Checked)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FullField_ERG", chkERG.Checked));
            }

            //Pattern ERG Checkbox
            if (chkPERG.Checked)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PatternERG", chkPERG.Checked));
            }

            //EOG Checkbox
            if (chkEOG.Checked)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("EOG", chkEOG.Checked));
            }

            //Pattern VEP Checkbox
            if (chkPVEP.Checked)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PatternVEP", chkPVEP.Checked));
            }

            //Flash VEP Checkbox
            if (chkFVEP.Checked)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FlashVEP", chkFVEP.Checked));
            }

            //Comb VEP/ERG Checkbox
            if (chkVEPERG.Checked)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CombVEP_ERG", chkVEPERG.Checked));
            }

            //Binoc PVEP Checkbox
            if (chkBPVEP.Checked)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BinocPVEP", chkBPVEP.Checked));
            }


            //ATTENDANCE
            if (dpdByAttendance.Text != "")
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Attended", dpdByAttendance.Text));
            }

            if (dpdTestedBy.Text != "")
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestedBy", dpdTestedBy.Text));
            }


            //
            //Awaiting Technical Report
            if (chkAwaitingTechnicalReport.Checked)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AwaitingTechnicalReport", chkAwaitingTechnicalReport.Checked));
            }

            //Feedback Patients
            if (chkFeedbackPatients.Checked)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FeedbackPatients ", chkFeedbackPatients.Checked));
            }

            //Interesting Patients
            if (chkInterestingPatients.Checked)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InterestingPatients", chkInterestingPatients.Checked));
            }

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
            da.Fill(ds, "personal");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            //Counts the number of results found
            lblResults.Text = "Results Found: " + ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Sum(x => x.Rows.Count).ToString();
            //Finally, all results matching the criteria will be placed into the gridview
            gvSearch.DataBind();

            //Adds the export button if more than zero results are found
            if (ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Sum(x => x.Rows.Count) > 0)
            {
                //imgWord.Visible = true; 
                imgExcel.Visible = true;
                lblExport.Visible = true;
            }

            Session["CurrentData"] = dt;
        }

        catch (Exception fe)
        {
            lblErrors.Text = "Error: " + fe.Message;
        }
    }
```

All help is very valuable to me as its making me very frustrated.

Thanks in advance

P.S, I've edited and added in the whole code to see if theres anything obvious I've missed.

Comment: Have you checked you're getting data from database when you debug?

Comment: I can log into the system so I'm assuming there's a connection. Do you think its a connection issue?@IvanSantiago

Comment: You can add a breakpoint at the line 'da.Fill(ds, "personal");'; start debugging and verify if you are getting data from database when you pass by that line of code.

Comment: Does it work without the UpdatePanel?

Comment: @IvanSantiago could it be down to the naming of the column names from the tables in SQL? It's pulling data from numerous tables...

Comment: Do you see data when you load the page the first time? If so, then putting the code that loads the data in `Page_Load` inside an `if (!IsPostBack)` condition may solve your problem (you also need to set the data source and call `DataBind` after applying the search filter, as suggested in thepanch's answer).

Comment: @ConnorsFan got the issue sorted - thanks for all your help. Just one last issue, the gridview is only displaying 1 result although when I run the same query on SQL it displays lots more. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the datasource to the gridview, have you set

```
 gvSearch.DataSource=(DataSet) Session["DS"];
 gvSearch.Databind();
```